# How to return value after event click

Tags: javascript

I try make simple case with 2 button like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function tes(){
    var result;
    $("#wrapper").html('<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>');
    $("#btn2").click(function(){
      result = "How to passing this value?, After button 2 clicked"
    })
    return result;
  }
  
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    alert(tes());
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

How to pass value of variable result after button2 click, where element for button2 exists after button1 click?

Comment: I think you will have to rephrase your question as no one seem to understand it in the current form.

Comment: your question is not clear. can you please explain what you actually want  ?

Comment: i need value from variable result, i try running it always undefined.

Comment: @KomangSuryadana can you use Jquery ?

Comment: @UsmanRana ok i try convert to jquery

Comment: @KomangSuryadana check my answer. let me know if you expected anything else

Comment: @KomangSuryadana accept the answer if it was what you are looking for and if possible edit your post to make it better readable for others to understand, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Ok as you've no problem using jQuery. I think this is what you want

```js
var result = '';
function tes(){
  
 document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = '<button id="btn2">Button 2</button>';
   result = "How to passing this value?, After button 2 clicked"
}

var button = document.getElementById("btn1");
button.onclick = function(){
 tes();
}
$(document).on('click', '#btn2', function(){
     alert(result)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Button 1</button>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Ps. You're trying to bind events on dynamically created elements and the way you're doing in your code is not the proper way. You can do that `$(document).on('click', 'DOM_Element', function(){})`.  Just to let you know so you should have an idea when working on `JS` in future

Comment: hmmm ok, i think on javascript can passing value after function process running all.

Comment: isn't it something what you want ?